# Подойдет ли java для создания десктопных приложений с GUI?

Tags: java

Я конечно знаю, что java используется в основном для создания корпоративных приложений, и каждый язык имеет свои сферы применения. Просто из языков программирования знаком лишь с Си, но написание десктопных приложений на нем "АД". Поэтому решил изучить ООП язык для создания десктопных приложений. C# не люблю из-за привязки к продуктам Microsoft, просто сижу под Linux, а mono не устраивает. Скриптовые языки не брал в расчет, хотя кроссплатформенность Python и Perl радует. C++ сложен в изучении, и требует много практики, нет защиты от кривых рук. Поэтому выбор пал на Java, книг по языку море, полностью ООП, статическая типизация. Но, как обстоят дела с написанием десктопных GUI приложений на этом языке? Удобен ли он в разработке? Если есть другие варианты, использовать язык X, вместо Java для этих целей, буду рад выслушать!

Comment: Чем mono не устраивает?

Моё мнение пишите под .net он как раз для desctop'а создан. Под windows быстрее чем java.

А на unix-like вряд ли когда ваш GUI пригодится.

Там тоже есть два подхода WindowsForms (старьё), WPF (тоже старьё но по навороченее).

Comment: А Tcl/Tk вместе с C не рассматривали? 

В \*nix Tk-ную часть можно вообще не встаивать в Си, а запустить отдельным процессом и общаться через псевдотерминал.

Comment: @Vladislav Pyatkov, 
> Под windows быстрее чем java
Пруф?

Comment: @avp а нафига tk (tcl/tk, поскольку даже при вызове из C, без tcl Вы там не обойдётесь) отдельным процессом?

Единственная видимая причина -- противоестественная аллергия на смешение языков. Остерхут своё изделие как раз и создавал для двуязычной работы.

Comment: @Vladislav Pyatkov WPF старье? Что же тогда по вашему "новьё"? 

@danpetruk [пожалуйста][1] Не знаю, насколько правильны тесты, но судя по этой статье у .NET есть заметное преимущество в производительности по ряду позиций
[1]:http://habrahabr.ru/post/120090/

Comment: @alexlz, на самом деле некотрые программы с такой архитектурой будут весьма простыми. Что-то действительно в духе \*nix. В некотором смысле аналог конвейера в шелле.

Простая (по сути консольная) часть на Си. Интерактивно отлаживаемое (через stdin/stdout) GUI.

Для передачи данных из Си в GUI в некоторых случаях можно использовать tcl выражения, интерпретируемые GUI по-месту. 

И т.д.

Масса плюсов. При изучении (написании) -- шаг к программированию правильной распределенной системы.

Comment: @kirar, выбирайте http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_platform-independent_GUI_libraries

Comment: @DreamChild на хабре часто появляются статьи от школьников в духе "Скандалы, интриги, расследования". Бенчмарк вообще никакой, причем для обоих платформ (ИМХО). Java "медленее" потому что:

 не сидит постоянно в памяти как .net -> долгий запуск

 JIT не компилирует сразу, а собирает профиль -> долгий выход в рабочий режим

Неважный GUI (AWT и Swing), плохо сочетается с JIT -> неотзывчивый "тормозящий" интерфейс

Comment: @kirar а какие у Вас требования к "десктопным приложениям? А то не совсем понятно, что же Вам нужно-то

@avp кстати, вот ещё более накрученное решение, чем Ваше. Трёхпенсовый Гуй http://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2013-12-07-24-days-of-hackage-threepenny-gui.html Правда тут возникает вопрос, можно ли программу с таким гуём отнести к десктоп-приложениям.

Comment: @alexlz, ага, почитал про этот Гуй. Интересно, но если откровенно, то непонятно. 

Так до конца и не понял, main loop внутри гуя?

Если да, то это очередной веб-сервер (видимо с динамической реконфигурацией).

Comment: @IronVbif я не имею целью защищать этот бенчмарк (или утверждать, что java медленнее чем .net), однако ваши претензии к статье по поводу java, не сидящей в памяти и особенностей jit-компиляции выглядят несколько нелогичными, поскольку если речь идет именно о производительности, то программисту в общем-то без разницы, по какой причине технология А показывает меньшую производительность, нежели технология В. Важна сама производительность. Ну и вот [еще один тест][1], правда старенький, но говорит примерно о том же 

[1]:http://www.rsdn.ru/article/devtools/perftest.xml

Comment: @danpetruk: одни только правильные дженерики дают солидную прибавку в производительности.

Comment: @alexlz: Это накрученное UI-решение? Нет, правда? Rich UI с помощью браузера? Прикиньте, как писать на таком программу наподобие фотошопа.

Comment: @VladD Я его в общем-то и не смотрел. В release notes http://apfelmus.nfshost.com/blog/2013/11/21-threepenny-gui-0-4.html есть ссылки на пару приложений и несколько примеров из дистрибутива пакета. Полнее ответить, увы, не могу

@avp могу только повторить, то, что написал для @VladD. Но там, на стороне клиента и ajax, и websockets

Comment: @DreamChild Мои три довода относятся не к статье, а скорее к теме "почему winform .net будет быстрее java desktop gui", которую озвучил @Vladislav Pyatkov . И java программисту придется смирится с этими минусами.

Статья на хабре плохая, потому что бенчмарки меряют не то, что хотел автор (и в случае с java и в случае с .net). На RSDN тесты тоже не адекватные, по крайней мере для текущих компиляторов (За 200х года не ручаюсь, но комменты там все про некорректность).

Comment: CERN интенсивно использует Java, для вычислений и для GUI: http://habrahabr.ru/post/43740/

Answer (score 7):

Мне кажется, не очень. Существующие фреймворки не позволяют сделать *легко* красивый UI нативного вида, а отсутствие в языке first class-делегатов и событий заставляют писать много лишнего «обвязочного» кода (Java вообще довольно многословна, а уж с GUI...).

Особенно не рекомендую Swing: ужасный layout management, никакая скорость, отсутствие стилизации и привязки данных, не говоря уже о вкусностях наподобие команд, анимации, трансформаций и декларативного языка типа QML — в общем, вам придётся всё писать вручную.

Связка C#/WPF в этом отношении гораздо более продвинута, но WPF нету под Mono, так что вы теряете кроссплатформенность. (С другой стороны, Windows всё же с огромным отрывом лидирующая десктопная платформа.)

Answer (score 4):

Все-таки я вам рекомендую посмотреть в сторону C++/Qt. Развивающийся, модный, хорошо документированный, кроссплатформенный, достаточно простой в обращении фреймворк Qt (который умеет больше, чем GUI (работа с сетью, БД, потоки и процессы, XML и тому подобное)). При всем этом - все прелести компиляции в нативный код, мощь и море доступных библиотек C/C++.

Зачем же себя так сразу записывать в неосиляторы? Сложность языка - плата за широкие возможности. Кривые руки встанут на место с опытом, глаз набъется на тонкости, которые отвлекают по началу, потом просто перестаешь замечать. C++11 и всякие плюшки вроде std::shared_ptr, помогут писать высокоуровневый код комфортно. И эти божественные шаблоны...как от них можно отказываться?) А const correctness и const methods? По этому поводу Кармак с месяц назад писал в своем твиттере, что отсутствие этих вещей в Java/C# - это шаг назад, в сравнении с С++.

Comment: @Free_ze: я не видел высказывание Кармака, но думаю, что const в C++ — довольно слабая штука. Дело в том, что `const` не даёт вам (да и компилятору) гарантий, что объект не будет изменён. Он даже не даёт гарантии, что _вы_ не сможете его изменить (`const_cast` никто не отменял). А значит, ни вы, ни оптимизатор не может воспользоваться этим для улучшения кода.

Гораздо более интересной и сильной семантикой было бы deep immutable.

Тем не менее, +1 за Qt.

Comment: @VladD, (только в смысле концепции) а mutable в deep immutable объектах должен работать?

Comment: @VladD Безусловно, но если стало необходимым делать const_cast для снятия модификатора const, то был ли смысл его ставить изначально?) Есть же mutable, которые вместе с const-методами обеспечивают логическую константность объекта. Если вы, скажем, решили что-то сломать таким образом и пользоваться такой недокументированной возможностью, то это ваша проблема, а не абстракции.

Comment: @avp: Существует два вида immutable: observable immutable и strictly immutable. В observable immutable публичные методы обязаны возвращать те же значения, но внутреннее (mutable-) состояние (например, кэш запросов) может меняться. В strict immutable ничего меняться не может.

Strict immutable можно безопасно использовать, например, из нескольких потоков без синхронизации, observable immutable — нет.

Comment: @Free_ze: безусловно, для поддержки инвариантов `const` полезен. Я собственно имею в виду, что он не даёт _гарантии_: компилятор не гарантирует, например отсутствие не-const alias'ов, за этим должен следить программист.

---
А почему это `const_cast` — недокументированная возможность? В стандарте описана, поддерживается всеми неигрушечными компиляторами, warning'ов не вызывает. Обыкновенная фича языка.

Comment: @VladD Я вас понимаю, но не считаю это недостатком. Кому, как не программисту, следить за целостностю абстрации?)
Ну а если объект, помечен const изначально, его менять уже будет нельзя, никакой const_cast не возьмет и оптимизации он поддается хорошо.

Comment: @VladD Недокументированная возможность не языка, а того модуля, с которым вы имеете дело. Если метод возвращает константу, то нужно считать ее таковой =) Согласитесь, незаметно для себя применить const_cast сложно. Таким образом вы нарушаете контракт, а значит должны знать, что делаете, и не обижаться на возможные проблемы.

Кстати, тогда уж можно бурчать, что reinterpret_cast и C-style cast - это ужаснейший недостаток.

Comment: @Free_ze: Вы правы, но хотелось бы помощи в поддержке абстракций от компилятора и рантайма. Хотя, C++ и не позиционирует себя высокоуровневым языком.

С моей точки зрения, `reinterprest_cast` — вообще преступление. Я бы ограничил его POD-типами, если бы в языке был гарантирован layout структур, но в текущем состоянии дел ничего (кроме UB) не гарантировано.

C-style cast ещё хуже, потому что он иногда reinterpret_cast, иногда const_cast, иногда фиг знает что.

Answer (score 3):

Java конечно подходит для десктопных приложений.

Есть немало приложений использующих Java в десктопе. Одни из самых, пожалуй известных это [Vuze (Azureus)](http://vuze.com) мультиплатформный торрент клиент и  известный юниксоидам [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org).

Общим во всех этих приложениях, является то, что Swing редко используется для GUI. Vuze использует эклипсовский фреймворк [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/), а OpenOffice вообще какой-то свой самописный вариант на базе AWT.

При прочих равных условиях, я бы посоветовал обратить пристальное внимание на SWT, фреймворк достаточно *mature*, покрасивше и побыстрее будет свингов. Краткое сравнение SWT vs. Swing [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306190/java-desktop-application-swt-vs-swing)

Comment: @Barmaley: http://www.openoffice.org/about/#history:

> The source is written in C++ and delivers language-neutral and scriptable functionality, including Java(TM) APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте почитать про JavaFX. Она как раз предназначена для разработки десктопного GUI. Можно еще конечно изучать старый добрый Swing. Все это входить в стандартную поставку Java SE 7.

Comment: По swing нашел книгу Портянкина, думаю для начала сойдет. Вам спасибо!

Comment: Изучайте лучше JavaFx. Он конечно так и не выстрелил, несмотря на старания Oracle, но как говорится, в конце останется только один, и это вряд ли будет Swing.

Comment: @kirar фамилия автора книги говорящая: Портянкин - :lol: